# Adding body class for logged in user kills checkout

Tags: ce-1.8.0.0

I have the following in my local.xml, to add a body class for logged in users (for styling purposes):

```
<customer_logged_in>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="addBodyClass">
            <classname>logged-in</classname>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_in>
```

Works fine, however, I've now noticed that it kills the checkout at the "Payment Information" step, with the following popup error:

```
Unable to set Payment Method.
```

Anyone know why?

UPDATE: The logs show the following error:

```
exception 'Varien_Exception' with message 'Invalid method Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Review_Info::addBodyClass(Array
(
    [0] => logged-in
)
```

I don't need that body class on the checkout, so is there perhaps some way to only apply this class to certain areas? Namely the cart page.

Comment: The exception that is thrown with this error should be logged somewhere. If you have logging enabled I would suggest you look into these files for a more detailed error message

Comment: which pages do you what this class to be added on?

Comment: It's really just for the cart page (checkout/cart/ or <checkout_cart_index>)

Answer (score 4):

One possible option would be to create an observer that listens to the event `controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after`. It would need to check that the action is only the one you desire and and then it could add the class if the user is logged in

```
if ($root = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')) {
    $root->addBodyClass('logged-in');
}
```

The reason you get the error is that the block `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Review_Info` does not extend the class `Mage_Page_Block_Html` which has the function `addBodyClass`.

Comment: Thanks for that. I guess another way would be to extend the Mage_Page_Block_Html class and then add an if($this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()){$this->addBodyClass("logged-in");}

Answer (score -1):

```
If_logged(true) == $this->addClass_body{
     var getCustomerStatus('Block(Referenced)');
     Mage_input=Tr()ll;
}
```